# MySQL non indexed columns in select clause

Tags: mysql

When i have both primary key columns and non primary key columns in select clause, EXPLAIN output under Extra shows empty as below:
Query :

```
     EXPLAIN SELECT   aggEI.c_id AS companyId,aggEI.uid AS uuid,
      aggEI.rating AS rating, aggEI.ei_name AS name
     FROM AGG_EI AS aggEI 
     where aggEI.c_id in (8)

     1  SIMPLE  aggEI   ref agg_ei_comdm_fk_idx agg_ei_comdm_fk_idx 8   const   65909
```

In the above query c_id,uid columns are part of primary key and rating,name are not part of primary key.
If i remove non primary keys from the select clause query is using index as below:

```
    EXPLAIN SELECT   aggEI.c_id AS companyId,
             aggEI.c_id AS uuid
     FROM AGG_EXTERNALINDIVIDUAL AS aggEI 
     where aggEI.c_id in (8)

    1   SIMPLE  aggEI   ref agg_ei_comdm_fk_idx agg_ei_comdm_fk_idx 8   const   65909   Using index
```

Where agg_ei_comdm_fk_idx is the foreign key index on column c_id .
Can someone explain me this behaviour. What combination of index do i need to have to make query use index

Create Table:

```
          CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `AGG_EI` (
           `c_id` BIGINT NOT NULL ,
           `uid` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL ,
           `ei_name` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL ,
           `rating` DOUBLE NULL ,
           `cnt` DOUBLE NULL ,
           PRIMARY KEY ( `c_id`, `uid`) ,
           INDEX `agg_ei_comdm_fk_idx` (`c_id` ASC) ,
           UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` ( `c_id` ASC, `uid` ASC) ,  
           CONSTRAINT `agg_ei_comdm_fk`
           FOREIGN KEY (`c_id` )
           REFERENCES `COMPDM` (`c_id` )
             ON DELETE NO ACTION
             ON UPDATE NO ACTION
           ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: judging the explain output both queries use a index...

Comment: @Stephan though number of rows for both the queries are same, why Extra column is different.... One is empty and other is 'Using Index'

Comment: Show us the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: @ypercube please find the create table in edit

Answer (score 0):

For unique indexes (including PK) the explain doesn't show in `Extra` column 'Using index' but that does mean its not using it ... in fact to be sure that a index is use you need to check the `key` column which specifies what index is use , if this is blank then indeed no index is used.

You can see the result in this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a5d9/2).

Comment: np, check the fiddle to see the example